# How can I make the category name per post at the same position?

Tags: css

If anybody can please help me. Actually I want to show the category name in the same position in the top left of the post box but when I am changing the title name of the post I mean when the length of the title is changing then the position of the category name is also changing but no I want to keep the category name fixed in that position. So how can I do this please. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do by making `.cat` elements absolutely positioned at top left relative to `.post` element

Add following styles to `.post` and `.cat`:

```
.block-type-content .post{
  position:relative;
}

.cat {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot. I got a great idea also about the use of "Position".